# hyper-v power off automatically

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Recently I installed hyper-v on windows server 2008 enterprise R2.
I also installed win server 2008 enterprise R2 on hyper-v.

After a while I noticed that hyper-v was powered off.

This is happening after every start. Each time hyper-v is powering off.

Host system is fully updated and there is no error log neither in hosts event log nor in virtual machine system event log.

What should I do to avoid hyper-v automatic off?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the Hyper-V virtual machine turns off (and doesn't automatically turn back on) every time you turn off your host system?

Comment: No. It starting shutdown while host works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an expired Windows version, you could try to run (from 'cmd'):

```
slmgr -rearm
```

Or, if you have the right Windows key, but didn't bind it to this vm yet you can use the following command to bind the right key:

```
slmgr -ipk xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to say the VM is being automatically shutdown, the "Admin" and "Analytic" event logs on host under "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V-VMMS" should have detailed information on what happened to the VM. You can also check "Hyper-V-Worker" events to see if you can find any anomalies. If not already enabled, you can enable the logs with following commands:

```
wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin /e:false /ca:""

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin /e:true /q

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Analytic /e:false /ca:""

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Analytic /e:true /q

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker-Admin /e:false /ca:""

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker-Admin /e:true /q

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker-Analytic /e:false /ca:""

wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker-Analytic /e:true /q
```

Comment: I checked all logs but thing is that hyper-v system is automatically shutting down when it is idle. In my opinion there can't be any errors. While I'm working on it everything is ok but after about 30-60 min idle it starts shut down as if there is some timer or schedule on it.

Answer (score 0):

run slmgr.exe and specify the /ipk parameter.